# Is Flutter will Vanish React-Native?

Tags: android, react-native, flutter

I am learning web development. I have learned ReactJS. I wanted to do App development. I think React Native will be easy for me Since I have learned ReactJS. But wanted to know Which is better Flluter or React-Native.
I have found that React-Native lacks in some features. The fact that google inventing a new OS called Fausia is Fascinating. And It's a sure thing that they will support Flutter in all means. In the sense, They will include all features? and Even Performance is way better than React Native since it will convert to Native Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first years of my development, I always wonder which framework or development language is my silver-bullet.

But, everything will be hard before it gets easy.

There are so many pros and cons in this choice.

I think you should pick a long and hard road.

If I were you, I'll choose Flutter rather than React Native.

But if you are pressed for time you should choose what you farmiliar with.

Comment: Thanks a lot dor Your Answer. I started Flutter